# Store the mappings between the math questions and the keywords through their IDs

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, mapping

This is my servlet which takes a math question and a keyword and adds them to a mathquestion table and a keywords table respectively. The query statement at the end isn't inserting anything into the mappings table.

The tables:

```
mathquestions {

  id unsigned integer auto_increment primary key

  question char(255) NOT NULL

}

keywords {

  id unsigned integer auto_increment primary key

  keyword char(30) NOT NULL

}

mappings {

  question_id integer not null

  keyword_id integer not null

  primary key (question_id, keyword_id)

}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);

      try {
          // set up response to client
          response.setContentType("text/html");
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

          String mathQuestion = request.getParameter("mathQuestionsField");
          String keyword = request.getParameter("keyword");

          String query = " insert into mathquestions (question)" + " values (?)";
          questionStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
          questionStmt.setString(1, mathQuestion);
          questionStmt.executeUpdate();

          if(keyword != null && !keyword.isEmpty()) {
              String[] keywords = keyword.split("\\s*,\\s*");
              query = " insert into keywords (keyword)" + " values (?)";
              keywordStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);

              for(int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
                  keywordStmt.setString(1, keywords[i]);
                  keywordStmt.executeUpdate();
              }
          }

          query = "INSERT INTO mappings (question_id, keyword_id)"
                + " SELECT q.id, k.id"
                + " FROM mathquestions q"
                + " INNER JOIN keywords k ON (k.id ="
                + " (SELECT id FROM keywords WHERE keyword = " + keyword + "))"
                + " LEFT JOIN mappings m ON (m.question_id = q.id AND m.keyword_id = k.id)";
            //  + " WHERE (q.id) AND (k.id IS NULL)";
          mappingStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
          mappingStmt.execute();

          out.println("<p>Thank you for participating.</p>");
          out.println(mathQuestion);
          out.println(keyword);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Curious why you use `executeUpdate()` until your last query when you use `execute()`?

Comment: Also, that last query uses `keyword` to directly build `query`.  The code is open to a SQL injection attach.

Comment: I'm trying to have a table where the user enters a math question along with a keyword so that the table stores both of the IDs

Comment: I used execute() because I didn't use a parameterized statement

Answer (score 0):

They `keyword` variable used in your last `INSERT` statement is not really a `keywords.keyword` value right? It's the value submitted to the Servlet which looks like it's a comma separated `String` that you parsed and turned into multiple `keywords` rows. So that part likely is causing a problem, it might not be finding any matching `keywords` rows (and is subject to SQL Injection as mentioned above).

I think your last `INSERT` could be something like:

```
INSERT INTO mappings (question_id, keyword_id)
SELECT mathquestions.id, keywords.id
  FROM mathquestions, keywords
 WHERE mathquestions.question = ?
   and keywords.keyword = ?
```

Essentially a cartesian product of `mathquestions` and `keywords` for the `question` and `keywords` you saved earlier.

An easier way to do this may be to retrieve the auto-generated is for `questions` and `keywords` you created and then use those IDs to do the `mapping` `INSERT`.  See [the MySQL documentation for how to do that](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html)

Comment: TY. The line that worked for me is 
query = "INSERT INTO mappings (question_id, keyword_id)"

            + " SELECT mathquestions.id, 
keywords.id"

            + " FROM mathquestions, keywords"
            + " WHERE mathquestions.question = ?"
            + " AND keywords.keyword = ?";

Comment: @user3436529 If this answer worked for you please mark it as the Accepted answer. Thank you